# Custom legend text on ASP.NET Chart bound by DataBindCrossTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, charts, binding

I'm binding an ASP.NET Chart control with DatabindCrossTable and everything works well, except the legend text that is applied.

My table looks like this:

```
Year     Week     Value
2015     1        530
2015     2        680
...
2016     1        887
2016     2        991
...
2017     1        990
2017     2        1021
...
```

I'm binding my Chart control this way:

```
chrtValuesByWeekByYear.DataBindCrossTable(myTable.Rows, "Year", "Week", "Value", "")
```

My problem is that the legend text is displaying "**Year -** YYYY", like the image below. How can I just display "YYYY" in the legend?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's plenty of opportunity to configure your `Legend` and `Series`, but when you call `DataBindCrossTable`, you're delegating everything to this method. The only thing you're left with is to overwrite whatever you want after the fact.

So, right after you call `DataBindCrossTable`, you can for instance, simply do:

```
foreach (Series s in chrtValuesByWeekByYear.Series)
    s.Name = s.Name.Remove(0, 7);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works well, but, is there a way to do it dinamically? Is there a way to control this, just like we can take control of x and y values with #VALX or #VALY tags?

Comment: Ok, I get it. Thanks!